# Find all the triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $ax+by=cz$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c,x,y,z >1$ if $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, find all the non-trivial triples of positive integers $(x,y,z)$ such that $ax+by=cz$.

#### Progress

I have been struggling finding the solutions. At first, I attempted to use Bezout's identity but I realized this approach cannot be right. Other approach such as $x=p c$, $y=q c$ only provides a partial solution set. Any hint?

Comment: I will not. Not without a good reason anyway.

Comment: @Prometheus, 
I have been struggling finding the solutions. At first, I attempted to use Bezout's identity but I realized this approach cannot be right. Other approach such as x=p.c,y=q.c only provides a partial solution set. Any hint?

Comment: Very funny Will. I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=gcd(a,b)$. Whenever $ax+by=cz$ we have $g|cz$, but since $gcd(g,c)=1$, $g|z$. So if $a=a'g$, $b=b'g$, $z=rg$, we are looking for solutions of

$$ a'x + b'y = cr,$$

where $gcd(a',b')=1$. This problem is solved in most elementary number theory textbooks.

You know there exist numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $a'm-b'n=1$. Let's fix such a solution with $m$,$n$>0 (this is always possible). one solution of the equation is then $x_0=mcr$, $y_0=-ncr$. Now if $x$, $y$ were any other solution, we would have

$$ a'(x-x_0) + b'(y-y_0) = 0,$$

but $gcd(a',b')=1$, so $a' | (y-y_0)$ and $b'|(x-x_0)$. Now setting $y-y_0 = a'k$ and $x-x_0 = b'l$, and plugging back in the above we see that $a'b'(l+k)=0 \Rightarrow l=-k$. Furthermore, any choice of $k$ leads to such a solution, therefore

$$x = mcr -(b/g)k,\ \ \  y = -ncr + (a/g)k,\ \ \  z = gr,$$

where $g=gcd(a,b)$, $am-bn=g$, and $r,k$ are arbitrary.

Now you want only positive solutions, so there must be some bounds. Since $z$ must be positive, so must $r$. Then for each such $r>0$,

$$ x>0 \Longleftrightarrow (b/gk)<mcr \Longleftrightarrow k < (g/b)mcr,$$

and

$$ y>0 \Longleftrightarrow ncr < (a/g)k \Longleftrightarrow k > (g/a)ncr.$$

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: A geometric way to think of it is like this: You pick a reasonable value of $z$, so the problem becomes finding points with integer coordinates on a line. You then start with one such point, then 'hop' along the line to find the other points. Since the slope of the line is $-a/b=-a'/b'$, the smallest step you can take is $b'$ along the $x$-axis, which becomes $a'$ along the $y$-axis in the other direction.

Comment: very enlightening.Thanks once again.